# NGINX ip_hash load balancing not working

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I've set up NGINX to load-balance requests to my web app. One front end server passes requests to two backend servers. All works fine.

However, I have been using the ip_hash directive to ensure users are served by the same server each time. This doesn't seem to be working - requests alternate between the two backend servers, and this is causing problems with user sessions.

The config should be quite simple, so I don't know where this is going wrong - any ideas appreciated.

```
upstream webservers  {
  ip_hash;
  server node1.mysite.com;
  server node2.mysite.com;
  server localhost:8080 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.mysite.com;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass  http://webservers;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post factual information about your issue ? Like the relevant access logs ...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, of sorts.

It seems that ip_hash is incompatible with the backup directive, and possibly with any other directive in the upstream block.

Once I removed the backup line, ip_hash works as it should.

However, this seems strange. I'm using a recent version of NGINX - 1.6 - and I can't find anything in the more recent docs to say that ip_hash and backup directives are still incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

backup
marks the server as a backup server. Connections to the backup server will be passed when the primary servers are unavailable.
The parameter cannot be used along with the **hash** and **random** load balancing methods.
you can find it at this link
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html